# Enumerating Child Classes for Selection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, enumeration

I am making an editor tool that allows me to add parts to instances of scriptable-object class I've made. I use a generic method to add the new parts:

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
class Whole : ScriptableObject {
  List<PartBase> parts = new();
  public void AddPart<T>() where T:PartBase, new() { parts.Add(new T()); }
}

class Foo {
  //insert selection statement that goes through each Child class of PartBase
}
```

The way I'm currently doing what I intend to do looks like this:

```
switch (EPartType)
{
  case EPartType.Bar:
    AddPart<BarPart>();
  case EPartType.Baz:
    AddPart<BazPart>();
  case EPartType.Bor:
    AddPart<BorPart>();
  default:
    break;
}
```

I am wondering if there's a way to do this that doesn't require me to switch on every single  sub-class of PartBase (so that users can add their own custom parts just by making a new script inheriting from PartBase and not having to additionally tinker with my safekept enum), while still providing some sort of enumerated selection that can be used as a drop-down in my tool.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can define a dictionary of enums and objects. Personally I like switch statements better for readibility.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate each sub-class and add it to the list! just add a new instance of the base class to the list: `public void AddPart()  { parts.Add(new PartBase());` later you may assign any sub class instances to the list: 'parts[n] = AnIstanceOfBazPart; ...`

Comment: @klekmek  is that to say there is no alternative that doesn't require me to write a new "entry" of some sort anytime i want to add a new part type, the dictionary still means i have the enum and the switch statement needs i need a new enumeration anytime i add a new part

Comment: @Behnam This is handy to know, however it doesn't change the fact that at some point I'm going to need to decide what class goes in to any give list slot, additionally, I cant do as you advise because PartBase is abstract

Comment: What exactly is your goal? As fallback you could still go for reflection and create your instances via the [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance) ... anyway though in case the `PartBase` is actually a `ScriptableObject` as you say then what is the good of creating instances via `new` at all? I would rather expect the user to create those instances via the assets create menu and just drag them into the slot in the Inspector ...?

Comment: @derHugo My goal is to be able to use my editor window to add parts to `Whole` instances. This window is a custom editor for `Whole` instances. The tool should allow the user to select a type derived from `PartBase` from a dropdown and then add the object to the selection of `PartBase`s in the `Whole` instance. 

My issue is with the selection process to decide which type of `PartBase` should be added to the designated `Whole`. I seek an alternative to using an enum and `switch` that doesn't require modification (adding a switch case here) every time a new `PartBase` derivative is added.

Comment: @DanielFamakin why do you need a new switch when using a dictionary? You can pass the enum you have and get the value by the enum key from the dictionary. This is a single operation. However, populating the dictionary is a manual operation.

Comment: @klekmek the point i'm making is that I'd rather avoid having the enum altogether, as this is a tool that I want people to be able to add their own parts to. Your way means there is an enum and a dictionary somewhere that each need a new entry every time the user adds a part of their own making. I'd rather keep the original package code clean and out of user hands so that their work is simply making classes that inherit from my bases and use the structures I have in place.

Comment: `I seek an alternative to using an enum and switch that doesn't require modification (adding a switch case here) every time a new PartBase derivative is added` you can use Reflection and search for all classes deriving from your base class. You can then create your instances via `ScriptableObject.Create(Type)` and pass in the selected type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this goes a bit beyond the scope of your question but here you go.

The comments in the code should hopefully explain every step

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Whole : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<PartBase> parts = new();

#if UNITY_EDITOR

    // A custom Inspector for this type to extend it with an additional button
    [CustomEditor(typeof(Whole))]
    private class WholeEditor : Editor
    {
        // serialized property for the "parts"
        private SerializedProperty m_PartsProperty;

        // tiny hack to simulate a dropdown (see below)
        private Rect _rect;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            // link up serialized property
            m_PartsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(parts));
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            // draw the default inspector
            base.OnInspectorGUI();

            EditorGUILayot.Space();
            
            var buttonClicked = GUILayout.Button("Add Part");
            if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
            {
                // little hack to get the button rect in order to place
                // our popup window here to kinda simulate a dropdown
                _rect = GUIUtility.GUIToScreenRect(GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect());
            }

            if (buttonClicked)
            {
                // Get the FOLDER where the current main asset is placed
                // we will place created part assets here as well
                var mainAssetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(target);
                var parts = mainAssetPath.Split('/').ToList();
                parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count - 1);
                mainAssetPath = string.Join('/', parts);

                // shift the target position lower to start the window right under the "Add Part" button
                _rect.y += _rect.height;

                WholeEditorAddPopup.OpenPopup(_rect, m_PartsProperty, mainAssetPath);
            }
        }

        private class WholeEditorAddPopup : EditorWindow
        {
            // The property where to finally add the created part
            private SerializedProperty m_ListProperty;

            // available Types and their according display names
            private Type[] m_AvailableTypes;
            private GUIContent[] m_DisplayOptions;

            // just the label for the dropdown
            private readonly GUIContent m_Label = new("Part to add");

            // Folder where to create assets
            private string m_MainAssetPath;

            // currently selected type index
            private int m_Selected = -1;

            public static void OpenPopup(Rect buttonRect, SerializedProperty listProperty, string mainAssetPath)
            {
                // create a new instance of this window
                var window = GetWindow<WholeEditorAddPopup>(true, "Add Part");
                // assign the fields
                window.m_ListProperty = listProperty;
                window.m_MainAssetPath = mainAssetPath;

                // get all assemblies
                window.m_AvailableTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    // get all Types
                    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                    // Filter to only have non-abstract child classes of "PartBase"
                    .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(PartBase)) && !type.IsAbstract) 
                    // order by "FullName" (=> including namespaces)
                    .OrderBy(type => type.FullName)
                    .ToArray();

                // For the display names replace all "." by "/"
                // => Unity treats those as nested folders in the popup (see demo below)
                window.m_DisplayOptions = window.m_AvailableTypes.Select(type => new GUIContent(type.FullName.Replace('.', '/'))).ToArray();

                // show as Dropdown -> clicking outside automatically closes window
                window.ShowAsDropDown(buttonRect, new Vector2(buttonRect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 4));
                // [optional] set position again since "ShowAsDropDown" might have hanged it 
                window.position = new Rect(buttonRect.x, buttonRect.y, buttonRect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 4);
            }

            private void OnGUI()
            {
                // Draw a dropdown button containing all the available types
                // grouped by namespaces and ordered alphabetically
                m_Selected = EditorGUILayout.Popup(m_Label, m_Selected, m_DisplayOptions);

                // only enable the "Add" button if valid index selected
                var blockAdd = m_Selected < 0;

                EditorGUILayout.Space();

                using (new EditorGUI.DisabledScope(blockAdd))
                {
                    if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
                    {
                        // get selected type by selected index
                        var selectedType = m_AvailableTypes[m_Selected];

                        // create runtime ScriptableObject instance by selected type
                        var part = CreateInstance(selectedType);
                        // Set its initial name
                        part.name = $"new {selectedType.Name}";

                        // Get a unique path for this asset
                        // => if already an asset with same name Unity adds an auto-incremented index 
                        var path = AssetDatabase.GenerateUniqueAssetPath($"{m_MainAssetPath}/{part.name}.asset");

                        // Create the asset, save and refresh
                        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(part, path);
                        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
                        AssetDatabase.Refresh();

                        // not sure anymore but from an old experience I think you need to re-load the asset
                        var loadedPart = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<PartBase>(path);

                        // add the loaded asset to the "parts" list
                        m_ListProperty.arraySize += 1;
                        var elementProperty = m_ListProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(m_ListProperty.arraySize - 1);

                        elementProperty.objectReferenceValue = loadedPart;

                        // finally make the modified SerializedProperties persistent in the actual "Whole" asset
                        m_ListProperty.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

                        // [optional] "Ping" the created asset => get highlighted in the Assets folder
                        EditorGUIUtility.PingObject(loadedPart);

                        // Close the popup window
                        Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

#endif
}
```

---

And here a little demo how this would look like

For the demo I created the following types - all in their individual script files of course

```
public class PartBase : ScriptableObject { }

public class ExamplePart : PartBase { }

namespace NamespaceA
{
    public class PartA : PartBase { }
}

namespace NamespaceA
{
    public class PartAExtended : PartA { }
}

namespace NamespaceB
{
    public class PartB : PartBase { }
}

namespace NamespaceB
{
    public class PartBExtended : PartB { }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()...` This is the key part that I didn't know about. This is spot on, above and beyond even, thank you! I'm doing it in a separate window rather than a custom inspector but I'll be able to use the bit's in this to do exactly what I need. Godsend.